# How do you report duplicates in a txt. file?

Tags: python-3.x, file

In our class we were given the task to basically create a program that re-enacts the US election last year. One of the extra challenges is that when you enter an ID number that is already in the file, it should come up with an error and just stop. However, when I try to execute this code, it comes up with

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

This is the code I've done so far...

```
ID = input("Please input ID code ")
if(len(ID)) == 6:
    print("ID length: Valid")
    N += 1
else:
    print("ID Code: Error")
    sys.exit()
with open('ID.txt', 'a') as idc:
    idc.write(ID + ' ')
already_seen = set()
for line in idc:
    if line not in already_seen:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Error")
        sys.exit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between the

```
with open('ID.txt', 'a') as idc:
    do sth
```

and the

```
idc = open('ID.txt', 'a')
```

In the first case, after the `do sth` finished, the `__exit__()` of the idc will be called to close the file object.

I advise you to use the second expression that I indicate above. If you are new to Python, this [blog](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) will help you to understand the detail reasons.